# TSLint stopped working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I worked on some projects about a month ago. Today I continue work on it. In meanwhile, I updated Visual Studio Code so my current version is 1.20.1

TSLint now doesn't work. I have my `tslint.json` config which was made before and TSLint extension installed in Visual Studio Code.

There are not any hints displayed in editor and also any commands does not work
[image]

Versions:

- TypeScript: 2.7.2
- TSLint: 5.9.1
- Visual Studio Code: 1.20.1

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm, whether your TSLint extension is enabled or not?

I had the same problem after upgrading the VS Code. So I just enabled the TSLint extension and it started as it worked before.